# Transform a dictionary into an object model

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary (like) object, with Field Name, and field value. I have a defined model already for many different entities. One of which I have included below. However, I cannot explicitly code for this one model, I want to create common code, the convert the entity model to the person model, or any other type of model. The idea, is that it could be any of the models, however I would know which at the point of execution.

In order to reduce code, I want to map these, based on the values in the dictionary, rather than, explicitly identify each field. The destination involves 100's of models, so you can see how it will greatly reduce code, and effort. I want to be able to build the model object, from just this definition, rather than mapping each field.

#### source

```
public class EntityModel
{
     public string fieldname { get; set;}
     public string fieldvalue { get; set;}
}

public class ListEntityModel
{
     public list<EntityModel> list {get;set;}

     public string GetValue ( string fname )
     {
           foreach(var em in list )
           {
                 if (em.fieldname == fname) return em.fieldvalue;
           }
           return "";
     }
}
```

#### destination

```
public class PersonModel {
     public string id { get;set; }
     public string name { get;set;}
     public string manyotherfields { get;set; }
}
```

#### roughly how it would work

```
public PersonModel Transformer(ListEntityModel lem) {
    

}
```

#### the boring way

```
public PersonModel TransformMeToModel(ListEntityModel lem) {
   var model =  new PersonModel
   {
       id = lem.GetValue("id"),
       name = lem.GetValue("name"),
       manyotherfields = lem.GetValue("manyotherfields")
   };
   return model;
}
```

Comment: use reflection maybe?

Comment: A really lazy approach might be to serialize the dictionary as JSON, and then deserialize to the class.

Comment: All those models serve a purpose. They make your code type-safe and they provide developers with intellisense, among other things. Don't just use dictionaries. If you don't want to write that much code, codegen your classes. [Disadvantages of using EAV](http://duhallowgreygeek.com/entity-attribute-value-eav-model-sql-smell/#:~:text=Disadvantages%20of%20using%20an%20Entity,but%20this%20is%20adding%20complexity.)

Comment: ok a few things for clarification: 1) how is `ListEntityModel` created? who is responsible for it? 2) are all properties of `PersonModel` of type `string` ? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public class PersonModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string manyotherfields { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public static T TransformMeToModel<T>(Dictionary<string, string> lem) where T : new()
{
    T t = new T();

    foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (lem.TryGetValue(p.Name, out string v))
        {
            p.SetValue(t, v);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

```cs
var props = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "id", "1" },  {"name", "one" }, { "manyotherfields", "m" } };

var instance = TransformMeToModel<PersonModel>(props);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection:

```
public T TransformMeToModel<T>(ListEntityModel lem)
    {
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        foreach(var entry in lem.list)
        {
            model.GetType().GetProperty(entry.fieldname).SetValue(model, entry.fieldvalue);
        }
        return (T)model;
    }
```

But be aware that an exception is thrown when when your `ListEntityModel`does not match to the properties (either name or type) of your target type. Also, your target class needs a default constructor.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fHBJlh